# Oracle materialized views workflow

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I am new to oracle. I wanted to know solution for below posted questions based on the details provided.

Questions:
1.  What most likely happened?
2.  How you would go about figuring out why it happened?

Details: 
The materialized view named SOMESCHEMA.SOMETABLE is present in an oracle database. It replicates rows from another oracle database. t is refreshed every night. While the materialized view has tens of millions of rows in it, it typically does an incremental refresh and the refresh completes in less than a minute. One morning sessions performing writes on your database are failing with many "ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS'".

When I run the following query:
SELECT owner,
       mview_name,
       master_link,
       refresh_method,
       fast_refreshable,
       last_refresh_type
  FROM dba_mviews
 WHERE owner = 'SOMESCHEMA'
   AND mview_name = 'SOMETABLE'

I got the following output:

SOMESCHEMA, SOMETABLE,  @"SOME_REMOTE_DB.EXAMPLE.COM",  COMPLETE,   DIRLOAD_DML,    COMPLETE

Comment: That ORA-30036 means the operation is too large for your undo tablespace. This is where Oracle stores the data that makes `rollback` possible. Give it more space by adding a datafile and/or setting autoextend on: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_undo_tablespce_alter_autoextend.htm

Comment: based on your select, it seems the materialized view is set to "complete" refresh which means it gets the whole thing each time.  "Fast" refresh is better, it only gets the changes, but you have to have a materialized view log created on the source table.  Look at the source system, is there table table that starts with MLOG$.  Even a fast refresh can fail if there are a lot of changes.  If that is the case, you can do a "prebuild" materialized view, where you can load it in some other way that doesnt use undo (like load it with sql loader and do it unrecoverable) and then go back to fasts

Comment: you can maybe try this "exec dbms_mview.refresh('your mview','F')" that will try to do a fast refresh, if it cant do a fast refresh it will give you an error.  or change the F to a C and it will try to do a complete refresh.  it is possible something else was taking undo space and that is why it failed, maybe it was an unusual situation.